# Images are not showing in WYISWYG editor

Tags: magento-1.9

I will explain this issue with example :

For example I want to set image for any product's description area so I go to WYSIWYG editor and click on image insert icon so it's open insert image section and after that we can see different media folder to select image.Now problem is here. we can't see any image here and instead of Image it's showing **ALT** tag.For selected Image url is something like this **https://test.hotdiamonds3.bathcomms.com/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvR2lmdENhcmRzL0NBUkQ2LmpwZyJ9fQ,,/key/d5d8fc754dd85fc475b1a8e17ae890c2/**

I have set 777 permission for media and it's subfolder.

I have attached image for better understanding.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Media Storage set to Database.

You can change this setting from

System > Configuration > System > Storage Configuration for Media to **File System**

[image]

Comment: one more question I asked please look 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123277/after-enabling-secure-urls-for-admin-and-frontend-css-is-not-loading-for-particu?noredirect=1#comment166967_123277

Answer (score 0):

For use WYSIWYG editor:

- Click Insert image then open a new popup window
- Click any folder of storage root(ex: click GiftCards folder)
- After that click Browse file button & choose image our local computer
- After that click Upload Files button. And image uplodaed and then click image, When you click image will be show button insert file & click this.

Your issue is not showing images, So you can use different browser. If you use mozila then replace chrome.

or

Use clear cache & image cache also

Comment: I am using chrome and I have done all above steps but images are not showing in WYSIWYG editor as you can see in image that I attached in my question.Any other way??

Comment: Please check once this path : media/wysiwyg/GiftCards
and confirm images are exits over there.

And copy path, hit in URL & check image display or not.

Comment: https://test.hotdiamonds3.bathcomms.com/media/wysiwyg/GiftCards/CARD1.jpg open this URL you can see that image are there and check this image name with the image that I attach in my quetion you can see same image.

Comment: If I select any image from WYSIWYG editor then it's show in backend and frontend perfectly but in WYSIWYG editor it's not showing.